# How to protect direct ip access in caddy

Tags: server, proxy, caddy, caddyfile

I've a subdomain: `api.example.com`

And I've a caddyfile that use a reverse proxy to redirect to my api backend:

```
api.example.com {
  basicauth {
    user my_hashed_password
  }
  reverse_proxy localhost:8000
}
```

As you can see I protect the access of this api with a simple `basicauth`. It work as expected. But I can still access the api without authentication if use `my_ip:8000` (for example `1.1.1.1:8000`). How can I also apply the basic auth for the ip direct access ?

I've tried something like:

```
:8000 {
  basicauth {
    user my_hashed_password
  }
  handle api.example.com {
    reverse_proxy localhost:8000
  }
}
```

But caddy is angry because I use a reverse_proxy on the same port as the one declared above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If port 8000 is not configured in Caddy, you cannot add basicauth in Caddy. You need to configure it in the application that is listening on port 8000.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not familiar with those kinds of things. So indeed, I simply modify my docker compose file, so the port 8000 is now only available on localhost. From `8000:8000` to `127.0.0.1:8000:8000`.